# Add conceal in function

Tags: functions, quickfix, conceal, location-list

Trying to maintain add conceals to the generated location list, but I can not figure it out.

The current workaround is to add it manually everytime through the vim commandline, like:

```
: set conceallevel=1
: set concealcursor=n
: call matchadd('Conceal', 'None', 10, -1, {'conceal': '∅'})
```

It would be less frustrating to automate the steps described above in the function below:

```
" function: list multiline block code as one line in a quickfix buffer
function! Overview() abort
    0
    let bufnr = bufnr('%')
    let items = []
    while 1
        let start = search('^{', 'cW')
        if !start
            break
        endif
        let end = search('^}', 'W')
        let lines = getline(start, end)
        let lines = map(lines, 'trim(v:val)')
        call add(items, {
            \ 'bufnr': bufnr,
            \ 'lnum': start,
            \ 'text': join(lines, ' '),
        \ })
        call sort(items, {a, b -> a["text"] == b["text"] ? 0 : a["text"] > b["text"] ? 1 : -1})
    endwhile
    call setloclist(winnr(), items)
    lopen
endfunction
```

Tried to add

```
call matchadd('Conceal', 'None', 10, -1, {'conceal': '∅'})
```

after the line

```
call setloclist(winnr(), items)
```

but this way of frankensteining the script didn't help.

Ideally, but not nessecary, it would be nice if the generated quickfix/locationlist respected the conceals assigned to the original filetype.

That would preventing me copying and maintaing conceals from the original filetype to the function. And it would make the function filetype agnostic.

Comment: you would need to call the `matchadd()` function in the window where you want to define the concealing to be defined for (as mentioned in the other answer). However you could add the `window` argument to the `matchadd` function for the dict argument. Alternatively, you could instead of defining concealing, do a substitute on the text item so that the text will be changed to the concealed characters. Then you don't need to conceal manually afterwards.

Comment: (too long comment, continuing here) Note, as far as I know, there is no easy way to get the definition of concealed characters for a buffer. You would need to handle this manually by parsing the output of `:syn` and processing the output of `getmatches()`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, and could I add the matchadd within the function that generates the quickfix, whereby the function presets the quickfix window with the desired conceals? Tried to add call matchadd('Conceal', 'None', 10, -1, {'conceal': '∅'}) withint the function, but that doesn't help. Thank you.

Comment: as I said, you need to call matchadd from within the quickfix window. So make sure to open the quickfix window first (e.g. using `:copen`)